# How to make the leading icon centered when the icon inside a FlatButton?

Tags: flutter

On dismissible widget I set a leading property like this

```
leading: SizedBox(
  width: 40.0,
  child: FlatButton(
    onPressed: _onPressed,
    child: Icon(
            Icons.satellite,
          ),
  ),
),
```

The problem is that the icon is not centered inside it's place (the SizedBox widget was pressed in emulator to highligth it's structure).

[image]

here is with debugPaintSizeEnabled

[image]

How to make the icon centered?

Comment: Have you tried to wrap your `Icon` widget inside `Center` widget ?

Comment: post your image with `debugPaintSizeEnabled=true;` - more:  https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/code-debugging#debug-flags-layout

Comment: @pskink posted it

Comment: @pskink https://photohost.do.am/_bd/2/93983522.jpg

Comment: @pskink it was without any additional containers and alignment property

Comment: Get rid of the button padding. I’m away from my pc so can not answer it. But the default padding of the button makes the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use container as a widget and set its alignment property as center and the child o f it as icon. like following :

```
leading: Container(
    width : 40.0,
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: FlatButton(
    onPressed: _onPressed,
    child: Icon(
            Icons.satellite,
          ),
     ),   )
```

Comment: you can use container directly. instead of sized box. edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your `Icon` widget inside `Center` widget

```
leading: SizedBox(
  width: 40.0,
  child: FlatButton(
    onPressed: _onPressed,
    child: Center(
            child : Icon(
                  Icons.satellite,
            ),
          ),
  ),
),
```